# How do I save 100 binary images into a single file?

Tags: python, image-processing, binary, save, binary-data

So if I have 100 binary images that are type .bmp I was wondering if there is a library I can use to save it into a single file then later read in that file and iterate through each image in python.

If there is no library I was planning on reading all of the 100 binary images then save them into an array in python then save that array into a file like `100_images.format`.

I was wondering in what format I can save the file to make it as small as possible? Since the images are all binary 32 by 32 pixels how can I do this efficiently?

I was thinking I could save the 100 images into an array like so:

```
array index
0             0 or 1 for if image 1 pixel at (0, 0) is white(0) or black(1)
1             0 or 1 for if image 1 pixel at (0, 1) is white(0) or black(1)
...
1023          0 or 1 for if image 1 pixel at (31, 31) is white(0) or black(1)
1024          0 or 1 for if image 2 pixel at (0, 0) is white(0) or black(1)
...
```

Then write this into a file in python. But I don't know what type of file I should 
make it. Then in the code that reads through the 100 binary images I would want it work something like:

```
binary_images_manager = new BinaryImagesManager('100_images.format')

for i in range(number_of_images_to_see):
    int[][] binary_image = binary_images_manager.readImage(i)
```

Comment: Would using python to compress those files into a zip/tar.gz file solve your issue, or is there a specific binary format requirement?

Comment: The Windows `ICO` format can save multiple`BMP` files - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)  - though I am not sure why anyone would do that. `TIF` can also save multiple images in one file.

Answer (score 0):

I would do run length encoding:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding

You can use one of the implementation for python:
https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding#Python

Encoding:

1. For each image matrix flatten it using np.flatten
2. Run length encode the image
3. Add the code to a list
4. After all images were encoded pickle the list

Decoding:

1. Unpickle the list
2. For each item in the list decode run length code
3. reshape the resulted vector back to the desired matrix shape